# animation is not smooth canvas

Tags: html, canvas

i have made this example

http://jsfiddle.net/mikulgohil/yc6Lb/

but the issue is that animation is not smooth
can you help me to make it smooth

Comment: Animation is smooth - you are expecting too much of your PC...

Answer (score 7):

To make animations smooth you need to use requestAnimationFrame() API.

http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/