# How can I move my JS objects smoothly using keyboard input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So I am new to HTML5 and decided to start to code a pong game. I want to move my characters smoothly using my keyboard, the W and S keys for the one on the left and the Up and Down arrows for the one on the right. I can't seem to get it to work. It's probably quite easy, but me being the noob I am, I need a bit of help. Thanks in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Pingedy Pong</title>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family:Arial;">
      <canvas id="ctx" width="699" height="400" style="background-color:black;border:2px solid black;background-image: url('background.jpg');"></canvas>
      <script>
        
        // STARTING SCRIPT
          
        var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle="white";
        ctx.font = '30px Arial';
        
        // VARIABLES
          
        var keys1 = [];
        var keys2 = [];
          
        var width = 699;
        var height = 400;
          
        var ball = {
            width:20,
            height:20,
            spdX:2.9,
            spdY:2.9,
            x:340,
            y:190,
        };
          
        var char1 = {
            w:15,
            h:90,
            spdX:3,
            spdY:3,
            x:10,
            y:155,
        };
          
        var char2 = {
            w:15,
            h:90,
            spdX:3,
            spdY:3,
            x:674,
            y:155,
        };
          
          // UPDATE
          
          function updateEntity(a) {
            a.x+=a.spdX;
            a.y+=a.spdY;
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
            ctx.fillRect(a.x,a.y,a.height,a.width);
              if(a.x > width-a.width || a.x < 0) {
                a.spdX = -a.spdX;
              };
              
              if(a.y > height-a.height || a.y < 0) {
                a.spdY = -a.spdY;
              };
          };
          
          function renderChar(b) {
            ctx.fillRect(b.x,b.y,b.w,b.h);
          };
          
          function checkInput() {
            document.addEventListener('onkeydown', function(e) {
                if(e.keyCode == 37) {
                    char1.y += 1;
                }
                else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
                    char1.y -= 1;
                }
            });
          };
          
          function checkWinP1() {
              if (ball.x < 0.33) {
                console.log("P1 Wins");
              };
          };
          function checkWinP2() {
              if (ball.x > 679) {
                console.log("P2 Wins");
              };
          };
          
          function update() {
            updateEntity(ball);
            renderChar(char1);
            renderChar(char2);
            checkInput();
            checkWinP1();
            checkWinP2();
          };
          
          //TICKS
          
          setInterval(update,1000/120);
             
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which bit in particular isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**: use `keydown` instead of `keypress` event.

The reason for this update is that arrow keys [don't trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3396754/5247200) the `keypress` event (or they trigger it but the event doesn't return information about which key was pressed). Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5597114/5247200) when you want more information about it.

---

**UPDATE 2**

I realize now the '*smoothly*' keyword in your question. If to call the `update` function with a short interval is not good enough for you, [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) API [is the way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7857741/5247200).

---

When you are programming a game, I advice you to use jQuery.

Try this code:

```
var characterSpeed = 15;

$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    switch (e.which)
    {
        case 87: //w
            char1.y -= characterSpeed;
            break;
        case 83: //s
            char1.y += characterSpeed;
            break;
        case 38: //up arrow
            char2.y -= characterSpeed;
            break;
        case 40: //down arrow
            char2.y += characterSpeed;
            break;
        default:
            alert("You have pressed the key " + e.which);
     } 
});
```

Here you have the snippet:

```js
// STARTING SCRIPT
          
        var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle="white";
        ctx.font = '30px Arial';
        
        // VARIABLES
          
        var keys1 = [];
        var keys2 = [];
          
        var width = 699;
        var height = 400;
          
        var ball = {
            width:20,
            height:20,
            spdX:2.9,
            spdY:2.9,
            x:340,
            y:190,
        };
          
        var char1 = {
            w:15,
            h:90,
            spdX:3,
            spdY:3,
            x:10,
            y:155,
        };
          
        var char2 = {
            w:15,
            h:90,
            spdX:3,
            spdY:3,
            x:674,
            y:155,
        };
          
          // UPDATE
          
          function updateEntity(a) {
            a.x+=a.spdX;
            a.y+=a.spdY;
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
            ctx.fillRect(a.x,a.y,a.height,a.width);
              if(a.x > width-a.width || a.x < 0) {
                a.spdX = -a.spdX;
              };
              
              if(a.y > height-a.height || a.y < 0) {
                a.spdY = -a.spdY;
              };
          };
          
          function renderChar(b) {
            ctx.fillRect(b.x,b.y,b.w,b.h);
          };
          
          function checkInput() {
            document.addEventListener('onkeydown', function(e) {
                if(e.keyCode == 37) {
                    char1.y += 1;
                }
                else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
                    char1.y -= 1;
                }
            });
          };
          
          function checkWinP1() {
              if (ball.x < 0.33) {
                console.log("P1 Wins");
              };
          };
          function checkWinP2() {
              if (ball.x > 679) {
                console.log("P2 Wins");
              };
          };
          
          function update() {
            updateEntity(ball);
            renderChar(char1);
            renderChar(char2);
            checkInput();
            checkWinP1();
            checkWinP2();
          };
          
          //TICKS
          
          setInterval(update,1000/120);


    //NEW CODE TO MANAGE THE CHARACTERS MOTION

    var characterSpeed = 15;

    $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
        switch (e.which)
        {
            case 87: //w
                char1.y -= characterSpeed;
                break;
            case 83: //s
                char1.y += characterSpeed;
                break;
            case 38: //up arrow
                char2.y -= characterSpeed;
                break;
            case 40: //down arrow
                char2.y += characterSpeed;
                break;
            default:
                alert("You have pressed the key " + e.which);
         } 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Pingedy Pong</title>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family:Arial;">
      <canvas id="ctx" width="699" height="400" style="background-color:black;border:2px solid black;background-image: url('background.jpg');"></canvas>
      <script>
        

     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, you maybe want to read this two posts:

- [How to find out what character key is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846704/5247200)
- [Simplest way to detect keypresses in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089421/simplest-way-to-detect-keypresses-in-javascript)

You will get to know about how to bind multiple handlers to the same event, the difference between IE and the rest of the browsers, the `String.fromCharCode` function and, if you are interested, how to write the same code with vanilla javascript.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it! :D